# GCC create command Assembler Fatal error message

Tags: gcc, fatal-error

I am new to GCC

When I try to use the create command on my c++ file

> gcc -c Kernal.cpp

it gives keeps giving me this error message:

> Fatal error: can't create Kernal.o: Permission denied

Comment: You are probably running this command from a directory where you don't have write permissions.  Check `ls -ld .`.

Comment: I tried to move it to a different directory and it worked. Thanks!